# How to prevent go back and browser refresh on react router v6 with antd Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm Using Antd Form and want to show a popup when user refresh or press back button. I tried various versions and now its working when user tries to refresh the page but not working on go button case and cant find the reason and cant use history.block because I need to do this with react router v6.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const ExampleForm = () => {
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
const [isDirty, setIsDirty] = useState(false);
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
// Handle the beforeunload event to show the warning when the user tries to leave the page
const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
  if (isDirty) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
    showUnsavedChangesWarning();
  }
};
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);

// Clean up the event listener on unmount
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
};
}, [isDirty]);

 const showUnsavedChangesWarning = () => {
   // Show a warning popup to the user
  alert('You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave this page?');
 };

 const handleChange = (event) => {
   setFormData({
     ...formData,
     [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  });
   setIsDirty(true);
 };

 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();

  // Save the form data here

  setFormData({});
  setIsDirty(false);
  history.push('/');
};

return (
 <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Item label="Name">
    <Input name="name" value={formData.name || ''} onChange={handleChange} />
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="Email">
    <Input name="email" value={formData.email || ''} onChange={handleChange} />
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
      Submit
    </Button>
  </Form.Item>
 </Form>
);
};

export default ExampleForm;
```

I tried another way using history but on going back nothing is happened, here is the second approach.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

version 1.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const unblock = history.block((location) => {
    if (form.isFieldsTouched()) {
        setShowDialog(true);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
return () => {
    unblock();
 };
}, [form, history, location]);
```

Version 2.

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const unblock = history.block((action: any) => {
        if (form.isFieldsTouched() && action === 'POP') {
            setShowDialog(true);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    return unblock;
}, [form]);
```

version 3.

```
  const [previousLocation, setPreviousLocation] = useState(location);

useEffect(() => {
    setPreviousLocation(location);

    if (form.isFieldsTouched()) {
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return true;
        };
    } else {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }
}, [form]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (form.isFieldsTouched() && location !== previousLocation) {
        const confirmation = window.confirm(
            'You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave this page?'
        );
        if (!confirmation) {
            history.back();
        }
    }
}, [form, previousLocation]);
```

Comment: I suggest using the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location) hook to get the current URL and compare it with the previous URL to detect if the user has refreshed the page or gone back.

Comment: I tried that way to, but when I'm clicking on back button maybe it is not deliver the state change and that's why I cant get the state when user click back. I will add the code here you can see it